# How would criminal justice works today if humans evolved hive mind?

Tags: society, humans, hive, law

Say the early humans not only invented tools but they also evolved swarm intelligence, think of the behavior in shoal of fish and swarms of bees.

Now fast forward to the present day, there is a special organ hidden in the brain which evolved over time to be responsible for intuition and it is particularly sensitive to the infra low brain wave emitted by our brain.

This is quantum mechanical so when people flock together or are within range of each other all affected minds become one collective mind, meaning they temporarily lose individuality.

Technology can be used to broadcast the brain wave frequencies over great distances, coverage is similar to GPS! I'm wondering how would criminal justice works for a hive mind world if any?

Comment: Questions asking "How would society respond to event x?" are often closed as too broad.

Comment: By criminal justice, are you referring to cops and court? Or you are more interested in how the mafia organization works instead?

Comment: This just requires too many assumptions to answer, including how a criminal justice system would evolve in the first place. Given the wide range of "criminal justice" systems we humans have had on this planet in the last 3000 years, throwing a telepathy-monkey-wrench into the mix would have a butterfly effect that would make the result completely unpredictable. Family relationships, Love and sexual relationships, work relationships, jury relationships, police and political interactions would all be completely different. That makes this question unanswerable, and is why I voted to close.

Comment: A hive mind might not have anything that is recognisably like a concept or perception of what constitutes criminal justice. This would place the question in the category of being unknowable. Pity really,

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how hive minded they are, they may not need criminal justice. If they all truly act as one there would be no reason for one to knowingly harm another. If the hive mind was less absolute and crime happened, it would likely be up to tribe elders or leaders to decide punishment as they see fit. With a more uniform thought process shared by this species there would be less need for a developed court system, as the vast majority would always support the elders' judgment.